# Call dbutils.notebook.exit() from a sql notebook

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I'm fairly new to databricks and I have a query.

I have a schedule job which calls a sql notebook

```
`try:
    dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/02 Processing Curated Staging/02 Build - Parameterised/MMT Processing - Migration Selection", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
except Exception as error:
# 611 Start  
#    print
    sys.exit('Failure in MMT Processing - Migration Selection ({error})')
# 611 End`
```

The sql notebook has about 30 cmd cells doing various task. I'd like to add a cmd cell at the top which if the result is 0 then it exits the notebook and fails the job. The new cmd could use the following logic

```sql
SELECT count(1) 
FROM $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_daily_demand_import ddi 
WHERE string(ddi.week_starting) = rtrim((
         SELECT value 
         FROM $env_tech_db.tbl_tech_admin_data WHERE type = 'Selection_Week' )) 
AND author = 'DCC';
```

I've been reading about the dbutils.notebook.exit, but just confused as hell. Is there an easy way to do what I'm asking. I'm only allowed use sql or python

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can create a python cell in your sql notebook to call `dbutils.notebook.exit("fail")`

create a python cell with magic command
`%python`
at the top of the cell.

then check the return code from your calling notebook

return_code = dbutils.notebook.run(...)